# type '(dynamic) => Product' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application, dart-null-safety

I am trying to consume data from an API. I used quicktype.io to create a model class to parse the JSON data. The JSON data contains nested maps.
Now I am getting an error
The error is [type '(dynamic) => Product' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform']

This is the code for API request;

```
Future<void> setSpecials(String restaurantId) async {
try {
  final url = Uri.parse(
      ENDPOINT + 'restaurant/specials?restaurantId=$restaurantId&page=0');
  final response = await http.get(url);
  print(response.statusCode);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final List<Product> specials = productFromJson(response.body);
    _specialsList = specials;
  }
  print(_specialsList.length);
  notifyListeners();
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}}
```

This is the model

```
List<Product> productFromJson(String str) => List<Product>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Product.fromJson(x)));

String productToJson(List<Product> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Product {
    Product({
        required this.id,
        required this.name,
        required this.image,
        required this.description,
        required this.isFavourite,
        required this.dishes,
        required this.diet,
    });

    String id;
    String name;
    String image;
    String description;
    bool isFavourite;
    List<Dish> dishes;
    String diet;

    factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Product(
        id: json["_id"],
        name: json["name"],
        image: json["image"],
        description: json["description"],
        isFavourite: json["isFavourite"],
        dishes: List<Dish>.from(json["dishes"].map((x) => Dish.fromJson(x))),
        diet: json["diet"] == null ? null : json["diet"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "name": name,
        "image": image,
        "description": description,
        "isFavourite": isFavourite,
        "dishes": List<dynamic>.from(dishes.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "diet": diet == null ? null : diet,
    };
}

class Dish {
    Dish({
        required this.name,
        required this.price,
        required this.offerIds,
        required this.id,
    });

    String name;
    double price;
    List<dynamic> offerIds;
    String id;

    factory Dish.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Dish(
        name: json["name"],
        price: double.parse(json["price"].toString()),
        offerIds: List<dynamic>.from(json["offerIds"].map((x) => x)),
        id: json["_id"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "price": price,
        "offerIds": List<dynamic>.from(offerIds.map((x) => x)),
        "_id": id,
    };
}
```

The JSON data is

```
[
        {
            "_id": "60edb147d91f7820c80585c9",
            "name": "Chicken Biriyani",
            "image": "localhost:3031\\images\\1626190484369-chicken-Biryani.jpg",
            "description": "Chicken, Motton",
            "isFavourite": false,
            "dishes": [
                {
                    "name": "Full",
                    "price": 200,
                    "offerIds": [],
                    "_id": "610e1cd618319924b45ef9cd"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Half",
                    "price": 150,
                    "offerIds": [],
                    "_id": "610e1cd618319924b45ef9ce"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Quarter",
                    "price": 100,
                    "offerIds": [],
                    "_id": "610e1cd618319924b45ef9cf"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "610cb83c231052429899df76",
            "name": "Shavrma",
            "image": "157.245.96.189:3031/images/1632371901688-IMG-20210922-WA0123.jpg",
            "description": "Chicken Shavrma",
            "diet": "Veg",
            "isFavourite": false,
            "dishes": [
                {
                    "name": "Plate",
                    "price": 80,
                    "offerIds": [],
                    "_id": "610cb83c231052429899df77"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Roll",
                    "price": 60,
                    "offerIds": [],
                    "_id": "610cb83c231052429899df78"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63331381/unhandled-exception-type-dynamic-welcome-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-stri?rq=1

Comment: @Lulupointu i tried like that but even without the .map its throwing the error